# Trouble building J2V8 on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, java, apt, j2v8

I'm trying to build J2V8 on Ubuntu 16.04 but I keep getting errors.
I'm running the install script provided on Github but I keep getting this error: (edited for brevity)

```
 make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/andrew/REUIOT/J2V8/node/out'
ln -fs out/Release/node node
cp: cannot stat '/data/jenkins/node': No such file or directory
com_eclipsesource_v8_V8Impl.cpp:11:17: fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE-----------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/home/andrew/REUIOT/J2V8/jni). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
```

I don't know what `/data/jenkins/node` is supposed to refer to because I know of no Linux system that has a `/data` directory.
I've tried re-installing OpenJDK to resolve the `fatal error: jni.h` but apt seems to throw an error when I try to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The script that is included is the one I (the author uses) on my CI server to build J2V8. `/data/jenkins/node` is the location on my jenkins server that I built node. The Linux instructions for building are in the [README](https://github.com/eclipsesource/j2v8#building-on-linux). You should refer to those instructions if you would like to build J2V8.

Comment: The script you linked in the README has the same `/data/jenkins/node` path described in the question. Does this mean we need to build node separately with build-node.sh, then change the node and JDK paths in the Linux build script to reference the appropriate directories? I'm trying to build a Linux dylib from my Mac to include in my project, so I can write unit tests that work on CircleCI (which presumably runs on Linux).