# Linux distro with '/data' in root directory?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, root, file-structure, j2v8

I'm trying to run an install script for J2V8 on Ubuntu and it appears to reference a non-existant directory called `/data/jenkins/node`.

I've never heard of a folder like that in the root directory, any ideas of what this could be?

EDIT: While this may be the same question as [Trouble building J2V8 on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38022398/trouble-building-j2v8-on-ubuntu), that question has no answer so I thought it would be reasonable to rephrase it more generally and ask it again.

Comment: It's probably just something someone added as a root user, and maybe then gave global permissions to others. Probably a way to separate /usr data and /data data.

Comment: Well you can create whatever directories you want under the root directory. I myself have a partition under `/data`. Probably jenkins uses that directory name too.

Comment: It is not uncommon to put data on additional filesystems mounted under /data or such. In your case it could also mean a null-expansion in an install script `$THE_DIR/data/jenkins/node` will expand to what you got if THE_DIR happens to be undefined or empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble building J2V8 on Ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38022398/trouble-building-j2v8-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

I answered this on the duplication question, but I'll put this here too. Tat location is just where I happened to build node.js on my Jenkins server. The build instructions in the [J2V8 README](https://github.com/eclipsesource/j2v8#building-on-linux) are what you are looking for.